# python sine and cosine precision

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, precision, trigonometry

How to improve python sine and cosine precision? For example I want to use follow code (just calculate y = cos(acos(x)) for a random complex vector x):

```
import numpy as np
N = 100000
x = np.zeros(N)+1j*np.zeros(N)
for k in range(0,N):
    x[k] = np.random.normal(0,500)+1j*np.random.normal(0,500)    
y = np.cos(np.arccos(x))

m= np.max(np.abs(x))

print np.max(np.abs(x-y)/m)
```

**y** must be equal **x**. But my difference is approx **1E-9**. I think is too big. For example matlab returns **less than 1E-15** for the same test. There is some way to improve python precision? Thanks!

Comment: What version of python are you using because I tried your example on 3.5 and 2.7 and both returned a E-16 level of precision

Comment: using ver 3.5, I get 1.2... E -15.  Also, (not criticizing, just curious) why do you need that much precision?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.10 32 bits (Spyder 2.3.5.2). I need good precision because I plan to use trigonometric function in some iterative algorithms. As result error can be accumulated from iteration to iteration.

Comment: accounting for accumulating error (in any language) could be a week-long CS course; for now, I'll point you to the decimal class in python, which may help you out https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Also 9.83356475295e-16 for me. I don't think this is an issue with Python, but with compiled libraries (Numpy would be my first guess) in your case.

Comment: Also check maybe whether you are not using 64 bit floats for some reason.

Comment: The version of python and spyder shouldn't matter. What version of numpy are you using and how did you install it? I also get e-16, both on my openSUSE numpy 1.12.1 and my anaconda numpy 1.11.3.  The fact that it is 32bits may be the problem, is there a reason you can't use the 64bit version?

Comment: Also, what do you get if you type `x.dtype`, `y.dtype`, and `m.dtype`?

Comment: Or, following my predecessors, does using `x = np.zeros(N, np.dtype('c16'))` improve your result?

Answer (score 0):

Before reading this: this may not be a correct answer, because it is extremely unefficient, but if you need extra precission, this could be the best solution.

You can use a `Decimal` class, where you can calculate with any precition you want (it calculates using string objects, not integers).

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 30
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857142857142857142857142857')
```

But the problem is that you will have to implement your own trinogometry functions. Luckily python website has provided examples:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes

```
def cos(x):
    """Return the cosine of x as measured in radians.

    The Taylor series approximation works best for a small value of x.
    For larger values, first compute x = x % (2 * pi).

    >>> print(cos(Decimal('0.5')))
    0.8775825618903727161162815826
    >>> print(cos(0.5))
    0.87758256189
    >>> print(cos(0.5+0j))
    (0.87758256189+0j)

    """
    getcontext().prec += 2
    i, lasts, s, fact, num, sign = 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    while s != lasts:
        lasts = s
        i += 2
        fact *= i * (i-1)
        num *= x * x
        sign *= -1
        s += num / fact * sign
    getcontext().prec -= 2
    return +s
```

Note that this will affect execution time of your program, because calculating with strings is obviously much slower than with floats.

Comment: There are packages like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bigfloat/. I would not recommend implementing your own trigonometry as these packages wrap efficient C libraries and custom Python implementations will be slow.

Comment: I think OP's main problem is that his Python behaves somewhat weird in that he gets e-9 errors. I wouldn't expect any issues working with errors in the e-16 range.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is disappear after  python reinstall. Thanks for comments